# Access to scope variable in custom directive dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I try to write a dynamic field validation. if a check box is checked a new section is shown in my page. As a result, in the new section some new inputs should be filled.

I write a custom directive like this

```
  <input .... multiValidation="Street,City,PostalCode" />
```

my directive code is

```
app.directive('multiValidation', function () {
    return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
       var parts = iAttrs.myvalidate.split(',');
           scope.$watch('CustomerModel.Billable', function (val) {
        if (scope.CustomerModel.Billable) {


            angular.forEach(parts, function (part) {

                var element = angular.element('[ng-model="CustomerModel.' + part + '"]');

                scope.$watch('CustomerModel.' + part, function (value) {
                    if (value == null || value == "") {
                        scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", false);
                        element.addClass("ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
                    }
                    else {

                        element.addClass("ng-valid ng-valid-required");
                        var validate = true;
                        angular.forEach(parts, function (part) {

                            if (scope["CustomerModel." + part ] == "")
                                validate = false;

                        });

                        scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", validate);
                    }
                });




            });

        } else {
            if (scope.CustomerModel.LastName == "" || scope.CustomerModel.LastName == null)
                scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", false);
            if (scope.CustomerModel.LastName != "" || scope.CustomerModel.LastName != null)
                scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", true);
        }
    }, true);
};});
```

my problem is in the following line, I cannot access to the scope variable dynamically in custom directive.

```
 scope["CustomerModel." + part ]
```

please guide me!!

Comment: if you are injecting dynamic form, angular will help you to validate those form fields. Use ng-required="true" in the dynamic form fields and wrap those form fields with ng-form directive

Comment: does it work if you put it in an object on the scope?  scope.object["CustomerModel."+ part]

Comment: @DavidKarlsson no it does not

Comment: @JagadeshK could you give an example please?

Comment: Try to do one step at time. 'requied-feilds' isn't a proper name for the directive, and scope["CustomerModel." + part ] isn't a proper way to refer to the property, and and angular.element('[ng-model="CustomerModel.' + part + '"]') isn't proper at all, and...

Comment: @estus what is the proper things ? if they are proper , they worked

Comment: These were the errors in code that were easy enough to spot. A bit too much for such complex directive. Again, one step at time, and watch for the errors in console.

Comment: the name of directive was wrong.

Comment: angular.element('[ng-model="CustomerModel.' + part + '"]') works well but as my question my problem in accessing the scope variable dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CustomerModel is also a variable of $scope. then I load CustomerModel form data base which it contains more property.

I can access to property of CustomerModel like following

```
    $scope.CustomerModel.postalCode
```

the following way is wrong for dynamically access to them

```
    scope['CustomerModel.postalCode']
```

the correct way is

```
     scope['CustomerModel']['postalCode']
```

the whole of code is

```
        app.directive('myvalidate', function () {
            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var parts = iAttrs.myvalidate.split(',');
    scope.$watch('CustomerModel.billable', function (val) {
        if (scope.CustomerModel.billable) {

            angular.forEach(parts, function (part) {

                var element = angular.element('[ng-model="CustomerModel.' + part + '"]');

                scope.$watch('CustomerModel.' + part, function (value) {
                    if (value == null || value == "") {
                        scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", false);
                        element.addClass("ng-invalid ng-invalid-required");
                    }
                    else {

                        element.addClass("ng-valid ng-valid-required");
                        var validate = true;

                        angular.forEach(parts, function (p) {
                            if (scope['CustomerModel'][p] == "" || scope['CustomerModel'][p] == "undefined" || scope['CustomerModel'][p] == null)
                                validate = false;


                        });

                        if (scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName == "" || scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName == null) validate = false;

                        scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", validate);
                    }
                });




            });

        } else {
            if (scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName == "" || scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName == null)
                scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", false);
            if (scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName != "" || scope.CustomerModel.customerLastName != null)
                scope.CustomerForm.$setValidity("CustomerForm", true);
        }
    }, true);
};
         });
```

and the directive

```
         <div class="panel-body" myvalidate="street,city">
```